# Dynamically edit dict tree in Python

Tags: php, python, reference, tree

I have a piece of PHP code that I am trying to port over to Python that I am unsure how to get working without references.

Essentially it's a config class that works like a tree, each key can have a simple value, or it's own set of keys and values. Part of the class requires being able to set one specific part of the tree without having to send an entire new dict for a root key.

```
{ "caching": { "enabled": true }}
```

For example, the above could be a simple configuration. And calling the below code would change true to false

```
Config.set('caching:enabled', false);
```

In order to accomplish this in PHP I use references

```
class Config
{
    private static $aValues;

    public static function set($key, $value)
    {
        if(strpos($key, ':')) {
            $aKeys  = explode(':', $key);
            $iCount = count($aKeys);
        } else {
            $aKeys  = array($key);
            $iCount = 1
        }

        $mData  = &self::$aValues
        for($i = 0; $i < $iCount; ++$i)
        {
            if(!isset($mData[$aKeys[$i])) {
                $mData[$aKeys[$i]]  = array();
            }

            $mData  = &$mData[$aKeys[$i]];

            if($i == ($iCount - 1)) {
                $mData  = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try to do something similar in Python

```
_dmValues = dict()

def set(key, value):
    global _dmValues

    if key.find(':'):
        aKey    = key.split(':')
        iCount  = len(key)
    else:
        aKey    = (key,)
        iCount  = 1

    mData   = _dmValues;
    for i in range(0, iCount):
        if key[i] not in mData.keys():
            mData[key[i]]   = dict()

        mData   = mData[key[i]]

        if i == (iCount - 1):
            mData   = value
```

It doesn't work, mData is the right value, but since I have written to it, it is no longer a reference.

How can I go about doing this? Is it even possible in Python, or should I just re-write my logic from scratch and give up on a perfect port?

Comment: What is global `_dmValues`?

Comment: @Marcin it's a dictionary which is global to the module. I have fixed the example, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with it more and realised I had the solution, I was just applying it improperly.

Each dictionary, even if it's part of a key of another dictionary, can be passed around by reference. Meaning if I change a key in that dictionary, it will change in the parent as well. Unfortunately I was changing the variable that was a reference to the dictionary, not the dictionary itself.

This works perfectly

```
mData = _dm_Values
for i in range(0, iCount):
    if i == (iCount - 1):
        mData[key[i]] = value
    else:
        if key[i] not in mData.keys():
            mData[key[i]] = dict()
        mData = mData[key[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your set method as follows:

```
_dmValues = { "caching": { "enabled": True }}

def set(key, value):
    global _dmValues

    key1,key2    = key.split(':')    

    mData   = _dmValues;

    if key1 in mData:
        if key2 in mData[key1]:
            mData[key1][key2] = value


set('caching:enabled', False)

print(_dmValues)  # {'caching': {'enabled': False}}
```

Though probably it would be better to remove the global value and pass reference to the dict as an argument:

```
def set(mData, key, value):       
    key1,key2    = key.split(':')           
    if key1 in mData:
        if key2 in mData[key1]:
            mData[key1][key2] = value


set(_dmValues, 'caching:enabled', False)

print(_dmValues) # {'caching': {'enabled': False}}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this would only work for a single colon. The example I gave was just that, an example, the string could have multiple colons and be several levels deep. Also, the module is designed to only have one tree, so there would be no point in passing it in every time.